# Jump ssh connection to Docker container requiring jump machine password

Tags: ssh, docker, ssh-tunneling

I am working on a remote cluster, where I have direct access to a manager node that redirects me to the compute nodes using Slurm.

On one of the compute nodes, I have a running Docker container, and I want to ssh into this container from my local machine. So, the situation is something like this:

```
local_machine -->  manager_node --> compute_node
                                         |
                                         V
                                   docker_container
```

On the local machine, I have a ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host manager_node
        HostName manager_node_address
        User my_user
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host compute_node
        HostName compute_node_address
        User my_user
        ProxyJump manager_node
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

So far, everything ok, I can just connect to compute_node with no need for a password by using:

```
ssh compute_node
```

On compute_node, I started a Docker container which is running ssh:

```
docker run -it -p 20090:22 container_name
```

so, from compute_node I can just use:

```
ssh root@container_ip
```

and access the Docker container from compute_node itself (it requires a password, that I set up in the Dockerfile).

The problem is, I'm trying to put everything together, i.e. I want to ssh from my local machine to the container.
I'm trying to use:

```
ssh -J my_user@compute_node:20090 root@container_ip_address
```

but now I'm required to insert the password for compute_node. I don't have the password, and I generally don't need it when connecting to compute_node directly. How can I fix this?

Comment: May you need this: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/using-ssh-agent-forwarding